# VLC player went pink

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, windows-10-preview

I am using Alienware 17 laptop Graphics GTX780M NVidia driver 344.11 OS Windows 10 Preview.
Problem I am having is that VLC player shows all the videos in pink.
[image]
However they are displayed OK on Quick Time player.

I have done some reading around and one suggestion that seem to work for people was setting `video > output module to > quartz video`. However I do not get this option.

**Has anyone ran into similar problem** (possibly on different OS) **and knows how to solve it?**

Comment: This sounds like a Nvidia driver problem; you will have to wait; for drivers that support Windows 10 to be released

Comment: @Ramhound I agree, however how come it woks on `Quick Time Player`?

Comment: Because VLC and QT uses different methods to draw the graphics

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it myself.

Go to -> Tools -> Preferences -> Video -> untick 'Accelerated video output (Overlay)' -> then restart VLC

Screenshot below
[image]

Comment: I just finished updating VLC and this problem. Thanks for the solution I was slowly going mad.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 and in VLC version 3.0.0 vetinari:

Go to Tools - Preferences - Video, then in the "Display" box, go down to "Output", select "Windows GDI video output" from the drop-down box on its right. Then click on "Save" (bottom right) and there you go!
(Indeed. I am now happily watching "The Girl Who Played with Fire"!)

Answer (score -1):

Set output video module to automatic. Just tried and it worked.